# Incrementing i when assigning functions?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create functions containing i in a loop, but i isn't been evaluated.

For example, the loop:

```
func <- list(0)
for (i in 1:3) {
  func[[i]] <- function(x) i*x
}
```

produces:

```
> func[[1]]
function(x) i * x
<bytecode: 0x0000000011316b08>
```

when I actually need 1 * x, 2 * x, 3 * x

Comment: What is `x`? Do you want a value for a string?

Answer (score 4):

Write a function that returns a function. Be sure to use `force()` to force the evaluation of the lazy parameter.

```
func <- list(0)
makefun <- function(i) {
  force(i)
  function(x) i*x
}
func <- Map(makefun, 1:3)

func[[1]](5)
# [1] 5
func[[2]](5)
# [1] 10
func[[3]](5)
# [1] 15
```

You could do this in a for loop with the help of `local()`.

```
func <- list(0)
for (i in 1:3) {
    func[[i]] <- local({i<-i; function(x) i*x})
}
```

In both cases the definition still looks like `"function(x) i*x"` but the environment where the `i` value is coming from is different.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your function refers to `i`, but there's only one `i`.MrFlick's answer is one way to force a local environment to be created to hold different copies of `i` with different values; another is to use `local()`, e.g.

```
func <- list()
for (i in 1:3) {  
  func[[i]] <- local( 
    {
      j <- i # make a local copy of the current value
      function(x) j*x 
    } )
}

func[[1]](5)
# [1] 5
func[[2]](5)
# [1] 10
func[[3]](5)
# [1] 15
```